# Reconcile acquisition/campaigns with User ID e-commerce transactions

Tags: google-analytics

We use Google Analytics on our website and are successfully tracking campaigns and submissions of our lead forms. At a later stage of the conversion process, the user is logged in and we use the User ID feature for all event and e-commerce tracking. Currently, we have two views in Google Analytics and it seems one view shows all data pre-login (without User ID) and the other view shows all data post-login (with User ID).

This means that we cannot reconcile campaigns with e-commerce results. I can't see the point even tracking any e-commerce transactions then. Is there a way to reconcile the two views?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the segment reporting in Google Analytics to filter the two campaigns.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

When the e-commerce transaction happens you should send an event to Google Analytics: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events   The event should indicate that a conversion occured and the amount of the purchase should be sent as the value.

This will allow the aquisition campains to track eCommerce value.